# How do I create a query that returns a range of rows from MS ACCESS?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Is there anyway to do a limit in MS Access, like I would using MySQL.

For example:

```
select * from cars limit 10,20
```

I'm implementing the database access in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to MySQL's 2-argument LIMIT in MS Access.

There is `TOP x`:

```
select TOP 20 * from cars
```

See: [In Access97 SQL how do I return a range of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091399/in-access97-sql-how-do-i-return-a-range-of-rows)