# Paging using access db

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

I am using ms acces database on asp page in c#. Database is very huge and transferring to sql is not possible because there is 3rd party software used for filling database.
Im using Olebdb reader, and my query gives 40,000 rows with over 50 variables. Sql query lasts 4-5 seconds. It is slow, but database is huge and it is hard to optimize.
Slowest part is when i am using queryResult.read(). Reader is assigning results to a List and of course data acces is pretty slow and i wait around 90 seconds to fill all data and show on website.
I have made some paging on List so it shows 10 per page, but List is still filled with 40000 rows.
Is there any way to do set some limit that read() return 10 rows per page than i request another page with my pager function?

Answer (score 1):

The first 10 rows are easy...

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM myTable ORDER BY whatever
```

but the next 10 aren't so easy.

Here are some similar questions:

[In Access97 SQL how do I return a range of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091399/in-access97-sql-how-do-i-return-a-range-of-rows)

[MS Access Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564024/ms-access-limit/)